# Logging in python package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am developing a package. In the package there are instances where I want to print information on the console for the end user. My question is which is preferred way to go about it, should I be using `logging.info()` from `logging` module or the simple `print()` statements is the way to go. Now generally I prefer to use `logging` but the issue I am currently encountering is, it doesn't print logs to console unless the end user initializes a logger.

Can someone please suggest if I am missing something with `logging` module or should I switch to `print()` statements.

Comment: Well, is it supposed to be logging for debugging, or explicitly console output/"UI"?

Comment: explicit console output, like a status. I want to inform user of how much percentage is completed in a loop.